# Periodic solutions for a 2x2 linear system $x'=Ax$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, dynamical-systems, cauchy-problem

> Consider the system
>
> $$\dot{\vec{x}} = - \nabla U(\vec{x})$$
>
> where $U(x,y)=x^2+y^2 + a xy$, for $a \in \mathbb{R}$.
>
> For which values of $a$ are the solutions $t \mapsto (x(t),y(t))$ periodic?

---

**My attempt: **

I recast it as $\vec{x}' = A\vec{x}$, where $A=\begin{bmatrix} -2 & -a \\ -a & -2 \end{bmatrix}$.

I know that the behaviour can be determined by diagonalization, i.e. $$ \vec{x}(t)=Q \operatorname{diag} \Bigl( e^{\lambda_1}, e^{\lambda_2)} \Bigr) Q^{-1}\vec{x_0}$$

I determine $\lambda_{1,2}=-2 \pm |a|$

Therefore the solutions $\Bigl( x(t),y(t)\Bigr) = \Bigl( e^{(-2+|a|)t}, e^{(-2-|a|)t} \Bigr) \vec{x_0}$

In particular, no matter what values of $a \in \mathbb{R}$ I have: *the solutions won't be periodic*.

Comment: You have $A=-2I-aJ$, $J^2=I$, thus $\exp(At)=e^{-2t}(\cosh(at)-\sinh(at)J)$. Or in other words, you forgot to apply the transformation $Q$ in your last formula.

Comment: But the behaviour is determined by the exponential of the eigenvalues, right? @LutzLehmann

Comment: Yes, if you insert the definition of the hyperbolic functions by the exponential, you get again expressions with the same exponential factors. The formula with $Q$ is correct, you just need to copy the missing parts to the last formula.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is normal. The negative gradient field points down in the height field of $U$. Formally,
$$
\frac{d}{dt}U(x(t))=U'(x(t))\dot x(t)=-\|∇U(x)\|^2.
$$

In a periodic solution the value of $U$ would have to return to the starting value after one period. That is only possible if $\|∇U(x)\|=0$, thus $\dot x=0$, which gives a constant solution.

Comment: Also, it has to be required that the eigenvalues are complex,so I have sin,cos combinations and in some case the $(x,y)(t)$ are such that $(x^2+y^2) (t)=\text{cost}$ @LutzLehmann So there is no value of $a$ such that the solutions are periodic

Comment: but looking at your computations, it seems that in any case there are no periodic solutions, which that's not the case for complex eigenvalues...  where is the flaw?

Comment: Full stop. The Jacobian of the ODE is the Hessean of $-U$, thus symmetric. All eigenvalues are real. Complex eigenvalues are just not possible with this construction. You would need a construction like with the Hamiltonian system for your scenario, rotate the vector field by 90 degrees or something similar.

Comment: Yes, indeed in this 2x2 case it's impossible to have complex eigs. Thanks. Just one word about the comment under my question: I wanted to use the fact that the behaviour of the original system is determined by the behaviour of  $$ \Bigl( e^{(-2+|a|)t}, e^{(-2-|a|)t} \Bigr)$$ (which are not the exact solutions, this is probably what you meant with your comment, right? )